# How to create shapefile by only used cells in flopy?

Tags: flopy

Actually my question is in the header. For instance there is a model with 2 stress periods 3 layers 15 cols and 10 rows and I am modifiying general head boundary package. After I edit the model cells by giving stress period, layer, row, column, head and condictivity values; I want to export that package as shapefile. When I use export function, it creates a shapefile but attribute table consists only row and column information which shows all cells in model. I want to see only modified cells feature in shape file with head and cond information for each stress periods and layers. Because, I will use that information to update the package values. Is there a way to export selected cells as features in shapefile?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to export selected cells as a shapefile. You would make a selection of the changed cells using GIS software or open source GIS tools after generating the shapefile of the package.